# me sale este erro al correr la migracion

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- active_support/basic_object
/mnt/c/Users/Gustavo/Desktop/SISMU-artesanias/rails/SISMU/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/mnt/c/Users/Gustavo/Desktop/SISMU-artesanias/rails/SISMU/rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/mnt/c/Users/Gustavo/Desktop/SISMU-artesanias/rails/SISMU/rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
LoadError: Too many open files -- /home/valdez/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/proxy_object.rb
/mnt/c/Users/Gustavo/Desktop/SISMU-artesanias/rails/SISMU/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/mnt/c/Users/Gustavo/Desktop/SISMU-artesanias/rails/SISMU/rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/mnt/c/Users/Gustavo/Desktop/SISMU-artesanias/rails/SISMU/rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Si tienes todas las gemas instaladas? Puedes intentar correr `bundle install` para verificarlo de todas formas